# Jmeter shows error when try to run script

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

**when try to run script with server-jmeter.apache.org and path-.***

it show result like below
Response code:404
Response message:Not Found in jmeter

want to check menu randomly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something which will work given you have a single [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, you need to do something like:

1. Add HTTP Request sampler to open `jmeter.apache.org` page
2. Add i.e. [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) to make X requests
3. Add HTML Link Parser as a child of this Loop Controller
4. Add another HTTP Request sampler and configure it like:

   [image]

You will get something like:

[image]

More information: [How to Spider a Site with JMeter - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-spider-site-jmeter-tutorial)